# Execution time difference between threading and concurrent module in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I was trying to implement threading in python.
I faced a situation wherein there is an unexpected time difference when implemented using `threading` module as against `concurrent.futures` module.

```py
import time
import threading 

def dummy():
    time.sleep(1)

start = time.perf_counter()
threads = []
for _ in range(100):
    t = threading.Thread(target=dummy)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
for t in threads:
    t.join()    
end = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Duration: {end-start} sec/s")

# Duration is always nearly 1sec irrespective of thread count
```

---

```py
import time
import concurrent.futures

def dummy():
    time.sleep(1)

start = time.perf_counter()
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = [executor.submit(dummy) for _ in range(100)]    
end = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Duration: {end-start} sec/s")

# Change in duration as number of thread increases:
# threads = 5    | duration = 1sec
# threads = 50   | duration = 7secs
# threads = 100  | duration = 13secs
```

Any pointer as to what is the issue will be a great help!

Comment: Try `ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100)`

Comment: Perfect! This brought down the execution time to nearly 1sec as I was expecting at first place. But, if the CPU/s are capable of providing 100 threads(in this case), why it didn't scale up and assign automatically rather than forcing us to use max_workers. If the rationale is to reserve resources for other I/O operations, then how was threading happy with it. Just curious.

Comment: Because that's how the default is configured:  If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5, assuming that ThreadPoolExecutor is often used to overlap I/O instead of CPU work and the number of workers should be higher than the number of workers for ProcessPoolExecutor. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the results of setting max_workers to 100+ in concurrent.futures.

```
Duration: 1.014041594000446 sec/s
Duration: 1.0162487380002858 sec/s
```

Taking from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor). The max default value for max_workers is less than 100. The actual value depends on python version.

```
Changed in version 3.5: If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5, assuming that ThreadPoolExecutor is often used to overlap I/O instead of CPU work and the number of workers should be higher than the number of workers for ProcessPoolExecutor.

Changed in version 3.8: Default value of max_workers is changed to min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4). This default value preserves at least 5 workers for I/O bound tasks. It utilizes at most 32 CPU cores for CPU bound tasks which release the GIL. And it avoids using very large resources implicitly on many-core machines.
```

So, in case '1' you actually have 100 threads all executing in parallel.
Note: The task is not CPU intensive so they are not affected by GIL problem.

On the other hand, in case 2 (concurrent.futures) the time is limited by number of workers.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch 100 threads in your example, you actually create 100
threads waiting during 1 second **at the same time** (so it takes
approximately 1 second).

When you use a thread pool, the number of actual threads is limited
(probably in relation with the number of available CPUs)
and all of them execute *some* tasks in a **serial way**.
Each of these *few* threads have to wait for its current task to finish
(during 1 second here) before considering another task.
That's why the total time is growing with the number of tasks.

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor
*"If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5"*